# Jackson mixin annotations not used when unmarshalling response

Tags: java, json, spring, jaxb, jackson

I am using a mixin annotation for handling `JAXBElement`s.
This is the mixin class.

```
@JsonIgnoreProperties(value = {"globalScope", "typeSubstituted", "nil"})
public abstract class JAXBElementMixIn<T> {

    @JsonCreator
    public JAXBElementMixIn(@JsonProperty("name") QName name,
                            @JsonProperty("declaredType") Class<T> declaredType,
                            @JsonProperty("scope") Class scope,
                            @JsonProperty("value") T value) {
    }
}
```

I am registering this in main Spring Boot class.

```
@Bean
public Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer addCustomMapper() {
    return new Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilderCustomizer() {

        @Override
        public void customize(Jackson2ObjectMapperBuilder jacksonObjectMapperBuilder) {
            jacksonObjectMapperBuilder.mixIn(JAXBElement.class, JAXBElementMixIn.class);
        }

    };
}
```

When i get a json string that contains a JAXBElement it successfully unmarshalls it to the real object, and when i check the debugger i can see mixin is loaded.

[image]

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/testNow2", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public
@ResponseBody
VAppType getVApp2(@RequestHeader HttpHeaders headers,
                  @RequestBody VAppType vAppType) {} // it converts json to VappType successfully.
```

But when i get json string as Response from RestTemplate it cannot unmarshalls the same json to real object and when i check the debugger jaxb mixin is not loaded.

```
ResponseEntity<VAppType> apiResponse = null;

apiResponse = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.GET, entity, VAppType.class);
VAppType response = apiResponse.getBody(); // it cannot convert json to VAppType
```

Why is the mixin is not loaded in when unmarshalling in `ResponseEntity`?
[image]